# QueryOver statement for selecting N rows with descending DateTime order

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

I am trying to write QueryOver statement for selecting N rows in the descending time order.

```
session.QueryOver<T>().Take(10).OrderBy(x=>x.DateInserted);
```

Unfortunately this is not at all working.
Is there any way to sort it out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You haven't specified if you want ascending or descending order in your query, so try doing like this:

```
session.QueryOver<MyClass>()
       .OrderBy(x => x.DateInserted).Desc
       .Take(10).List();
```

At the end you have to call **List** to get a collection containing the results, and don't forget to replace the generic type **T** by your class name.

Comment: Maybe .Desc() ? (method)

Comment: @heringer No, it is a property.